# Magento 2 - What is the Event name after customer edit address only

Tags: magento2.3, customer, event-observer, customer-account, customer-address

I need to use events 2 places

1 - When customer verified email

```
 <event name="controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_confirm">
        <observer name="insert_customer_info_cova" instance="Company\Namespace\Observer\InsertCustomerInfo"/>
    </event>
```

2 - When customer edit address information

```
<event name="customer_address_save_after">
        <observer name="update_customer_address_cova" instance="Company\Namespace\Observer\UpdateCustomerAddress" />
    </event>
```

It is working fine when customer registration page have no address fields but when we are showing address fields on registration page then this event is fire "customer_address_save_after"

So I need to block that "customer_address_save_after" event when customer register on registration page

Anyone know how to block that event ?

Answer (score 2):

You can check referUrl and set condition according that

use below code to check referUrl

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$refeUrl = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface')->getRefererUrl();
```

**You should not use the ObjectManager directly!**

Comment: ok checking,yes may be it works

Comment: i did it other way upvote for your answer